# Regex to find two words next to each other based on first character

Tags: regex, notepad++

I've been given some abbreviations, and I'm attempting to find possible word groupings that the abbreviations would be from.

For example, if you had been given the abbreviation mp, I would like to use regex to find the word pair "monthly premium".

So far, I've tried `\bm.*\bp`, but it ends of overshooting and grabbing entire sentences.

I'm using notepad++. Thanks

Comment: I added a \b to the suggestion from @ElBaulP and it works. \bm\w*\sp\w*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do not know about Notepad++, but here is a simple example that will do it:

```
\bm\w*\sp\w*
```

- `\w`: Matches any word character (alphanumeric & underscore). Only matches low-ascii characters (no accented or non-roman characters). Equivalent to [A-Za-z0-9_]
- `\s` Matches any whitespace character (spaces, tabs, line breaks).

You can test it here: https://regexr.com/4a84e
(edited, added \b in front of the solution)

Comment: `\w` matches all letters, not only `[a-zA-Z]`

Comment: @JoshBeauregard: Npp uses [boost regex engine](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/libs/regex/doc/html/boost_regex/format/boost_format_syntax.html)

Comment: @toto, I copied the documentation from regexr.

Comment: @ElBaulP Thank you. Your solution almost worked in Notepad++, except it was not searching for the beginning of the first word. I added a \b to the beginning of your solution and it worked!!  \bm\w*\sp\w*

Comment: @JohnFerguson If you have a few abbreviations, you could build the regex for each one on the fly insstead of creating one regex for each one manually.

Comment: @ElBaulP Could you explain how to do that?

Comment: @JohnFerguson You would need a programming language, Python for example.